# Android: Does onCreate method run in tabView when we click on each tab?

Tags: android, image, tableview

In my project I have three tabs. I want to know, each time that I click a tab onCreate function runs or it runs just one time when it creates.

Actually, in one tab I want to show a picture. for the first time, default picture is shown. However, if user creates his picture (in other tabs), when he clicks this tab the new picture should be shown.

My problem is, only default picture is shown and it doesn't show new picture. I think onCreate method don't run each time that I click the tab. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi friend it depends up on whether the activity is still active or not, if the activity is in paused mode then only the onResume() method  will be called, if the activity is destroyed then the onCreate() method will be called,

my suggestions is that if u want to  write any code u can use onResume()

or else

u can explicitly kill previous activities  using finish method of activity. to make sure that every time onCreate() method is invoked..

u can call this finish() in the tab class u have written for tabs before switching to other tabs

Comment: Thanks Ramesh your suggestion or trick was amazing :)  after I run the program, when I click on tab, it crashes. I think it's because of my code. In first try{} I told that show the user picture and in catch{} I told that if there was not user picture, show default picture. I think because of this my program crashes. what is your suggestion? Thanks again

Comment: i can't suggest anything  unless i see u r code, u must conform that the exception is thrown when the picture is not available. and i also suggest that be careful when ever use these finish() method activity. and after finishing this activity u need to proper intent to invoke next tab activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Copied the same code in onResume() method & it worked as expected.